# Line integral about a circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Here is the question: Evaluate$$\int Pdx+Qdy$$ where $$P(x,y)=\frac{y+x}{x^2+y^2}$$ and $$Q(x,y)=\frac{y-x}{x^2+y^2}$$ about the circle $$C: x^2+y^2=a$$ oriented clockwise. I tried finding $P_y$ and $Q_x$ and I got $0$. However, that is not the answer. I know it is because the function is discontinuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$, but I don't know what to do about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t)),t\in [\alpha,\beta]$ is an oriented parametrization of the circle $C:x^2+y^2=a$ then $$\int_C Pdx+Qdy=\int_\alpha^\beta\left[P(x(t),y(t))x'(t)+Q(x(t),y(t))y'(t)\right]dt$$ by definition.

I am sure that you know at least one parametrization of a circle of radius $\sqrt{a}$, so all you need now is to compute the integral on the right-hand side.

Comment: I solved this integral using the parameterization $x=\sqrt a\cos(t)$ and $y=\sqrt a\sin(t)$ where $t$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$. The answer I get is $0$. However, that is not right.

Comment: You should check again your calculus. Furthermore, the parametrization you use is not well oriented. Anyway, with your $x(t),y(t)$, what did you get for $P(x(t),y(t))x'(t)+Q(x(t),y(t))y'(t)$ ?

Comment: $\cos^2t-\sin^2t-2 \cos t \sin t$ from $0$ to $2\pi$

Comment: No, you got a problem of signs. Maybe with the derivative of $x$ and $y$ : $x'(t)=-\sqrt{a}\sin(t)$ and $y'(t)=\sqrt{a}\cos(t)$.

Comment: Ok this is what I got: $$\frac{(\sqrt a \cos t +\sqrt a \sin t)(-\sqrt a \sin t)+(-\sqrt a \cos t + \sqrt a \sin t )(\sqrt a \cos t)}{a}$$

Comment: Ah! Ok! I got it :) Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome :) If you did it right, you should get $2\pi$.

Comment: $2\pi$? or $-2\pi$?

Comment: $2\pi$. As I already said, the parametrization you choose does not have the clockwise orientation, so you need to put a minus sign before your calculus to get the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the derivatives, did you get
$$
P_y=Q_x=\frac{x^2-2xy-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}?
$$
You can use polar coordinates 
$$
x=a\cos\theta
$$
$$
y=a\sin\theta
$$
to get
$$
\frac{a^2\cos^2\theta-2a^2\cos\theta\sin\theta-a^2\sin^2\theta}{a^4}.
$$